# Why is my Angular.js $routeProvider doing nothing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application

I'm learning Angular.js right now by following along with the videos at Egghead.io. I'm at [the $routeProvider video](http://egghead.io/video/angularjs-routeprovider-api/), and my app isn't routing at all.

It's ultra basic, here's the script (app.js):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// routes
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/pizza', { template: 'Yum!!' });
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = { message: "Hello" };
});
```

And the html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    {{data.message + " world"}}
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

From my understanding, `http://host/#/pizza` should simply show "Yum!!" since I'm passing a string in the template. It doesn't appear to do anything though, I still get "Hello world" as evaluated by the `FirstCtrl`.

Why isn't the `$routeProvider` doing anything in my app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to put an `ng-view` element in where you want the routeProvider to stick the page's template.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        {{data.message + " world"}}
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that indicating it like below keeps you cross-browser compliant.

```
<div ng-view> </div>
```

or, for that matter:

```
<ANY ng-view> </ANY>
```

More information is available here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView

Comment: Not terribly important, but missing `<` in your 2nd code block.